# SSRS Report Subscription emails stopped sending

Tags: reporting-services, subscriptions

Our reports in SSRS stopped sending. The last report was sent 2 days ago, and was send successfully, but since then none of the reports are being sent.

If I look at the SSRS web page for each report, there is no error. Simply showing the last run time as 2 days ago, so seems it didn't even try send.

Yesterday we did make some changes. But only moving a database from the Express version, to the regular version. We did not do anything that would affect the SSRS metadata (or at least we don't think we did...)

Where should we start looking to see why the report subscriptions stopped? Is there a process that could have accidentally been disabled? Thank you!

Comment: When you say you moved the database, are you talking about the ReportServer database? When you say moved, did you copy it to a different instance?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer. No we didn't touch that database. We duplicated other databases to the same instance as where the ReportServer data is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Report subscriptions are created as jobs for the SQL Agent. You should see a long list of jobs with GUIDs as the names. Make sure that the SQL agent jobs are running. Going through the Steps of the [SQL Reporting Services Configuration tool](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156305%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) will recreate these jobs if you were to move the Reporting Service installation to another server. (I don't recall which step recreates the subscriptions. Just go through each pane and click "Apply.")

Depending on how you move things, you may need to backup and restore encryption keys, and you can easily end up in a state where two copies of subscription exist and are executed ( on different servers.) But in your case, where you didn't move SSRS, I'd look at the SQL Agent properties on the original server (Express) to see that the SQL agent is enabled and running, and check the history of the SQL Agent jobs, to see if there are any problems.

Comment: Checked. Everything looks correct, but our IT may have re-enabled it. I will check if the reports go out tonight correctly, and if not will investigate further. Thank you.

Comment: everything is working correctly now. We must have accidentally disabled the jobs. Thank you.